# Get editText value to display on textView

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-edittext, settext

I have 2 Activity. I get the text by:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Directory!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, CardBox.class);

EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
EditText txtCompany= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCompany);
EditText txtPhone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
EditText txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
EditText txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
EditText txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
EditText txtWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
EditText txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

String Name=txtName.getText().toString(),
Company=txtCompany.getText().toString(), 
Phone=txtPhone.getText().toString(), 
Mobile=txtMobile.getText().toString(), Address=txtAddress.getText().toString(), 
Email=txtEmail.getText().toString(), Website=txtWebsite.getText().toString(), 
Title=txtTitle.getText().toString();

intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Name);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Company);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Phone);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Mobile);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Address);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Email);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Website); 
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Title);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

and i set it on textView by:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_box);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent;
    intent = getIntent();
    String Name = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Company = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Phone = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Mobile = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Address = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Email = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Website = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String Title = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Display the message in textview
    TextView stv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv1);
    TextView stv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv2);
    TextView stv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv3);
    TextView stv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv4);
    TextView stv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv5);
    TextView stv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv6);
    TextView stv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv7);
    TextView stv8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stv8);

    stv1.setText(Name);
    stv2.setText(Company);
    stv3.setText(Phone);
    stv4.setText(Mobile);
    stv5.setText(Address);
    stv6.setText(Email);
    stv7.setText(Website);
    stv8.setText(Title);
```

Finally when i clicked 'Save' button. New Activity opens and i see all of the textView are set to stv8.setText(Title).

What is wrong? There is no error!

Comment: did you try the suggestion in my post??

Comment: I firstly implemented yours, but then i was unable to set the text with no error. But i guess it is because of some missing parts i did. Then i tried the shortest suggestion below which is working. But since i work on these coding several times, i will try to implement again. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your keys are the same `NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE`. That is why all  strings from name to title are the same. You need different keys

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Name);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Company);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Phone);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Mobile);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Address);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Email);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Website);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, Title);
```

Then you have

```
String Name = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Company = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Phone = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Mobile = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Address = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Email = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Website = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String Title = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

What you need in `NewCard`

```
public final static String EXTRA_NAME = "com.example.myfirstapp.NAME";
public final static String EXTRA_COMPANY = "com.example.myfirstapp.COMPANY";
... // similarly for others
```

Then

intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, Name);
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COMPANY, Company);
   ... // similarly for others
Then in SecondActivity

```
String Name = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_NAME);
String Name = intent.getStringExtra(NewCard.EXTRA_COMPANY);
... // similarly for others
```

I guess you followed

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

But you also need different keys

`public Intent putExtra (String name, String value)`

Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a **package prefix**, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like (Example)`"com.android.contacts.ShowAll".`

Parameters

```
name    The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
value   The String data value.
```

Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes!

In the first activity

```
intent.putExtra("name", Name);
```

in the second:

```
String Name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

repeat this for all fields!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE" can be used for every value . I haven't used this approach before . How the code is supposed to distinguish between two values while using Intent.getStringExtra() with same parameter "NewCard.EXTRA_MESSAGE" every time ?

You can use following method . In the activity where you collect data from EditText add Following code

```
  Bundle data=new Bundle();
  data.putString("name",Name);
  data.putString("company",Company);
  data.putString("email",Email);
  data.putString("addr",Address);
  data.putString("title",Title);
  data.putString("web",Website);
  data.putString("ph",Phone);
  intent.putExtra("bun",data);
```

In the another activity where you put the values in TextView add following code in onCreate Method

```
     Bundle bun=this.getIntent().getBundleExtra("bun"); // FIXED THIS LINE
     String Name=bun.getString("name");
     String Email=bun.getString("email");
     String Address=bun.getString("addr");
      // AND EXTRACT ALL OTHER VALUES USING CORRESPONDING KEYS IN SIMILAR MANNER
```

Comment: Since i remove intent.putExtra lines and replace this, and also replace all String with this data.xxx: my app stop running after clicking 'Save' button. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3009341 It should work properly. If it is not working properly means you haven't implemented it properly.Can you add the recent code in your question ?

Comment: @user3009341 OK there was a minute error in my code.I have fixed it in answer. See the second part of code . It should work now

Comment: Can you please let me know which parts of my coding should i replace in case if i am implementing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @user3009341 The very first line of code which is related to second activity . See my answer i have added text " FIXED THIS LINE" after  that line in comments